# Does Robertson know who the Fizzle Bomber is?

Tags: predestination

In the Predestination movie, the true nature of the infamous "Fizzle Bomber" is unknown until the end, at least for John/Jane/Barkeep.

But the question is, does Robertson - the boss at the Temporal Agency - know who the terrorist is? You could say "no" since he lets John retire so close to the big attack (probably with the hope that his agent has one more chance to stop the attack), but then when he says his goodbyes, he said:

> He made you a better Agent. We've all learned things from him. He's made us better at our jobs. This organization wouldn't have grown if it wasn't for the Fizzle Bomber.

So does Robertson know who the Bomber is?

Comment: This is one of my favorite movies.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is deliberately left vague, the implication is that he does know.

Robertson was aware that multiple time hops was bad for your mental state.
It is clear that the Fizzle Bomber made many hops, otherwise he would not have collected the press cuttings of mass killings that he claimed to have averted.

Robertson stated that he no longer time hops unless absolutely necessary, so has effective retreated to what he perceives, or knows, to be a safe timeline.  He also knows of the encounter in which our hero receives the burns while fighting the bomber.

The statement that "*He made you a better agent*" hints, as you suggest, that tracking the bomber and repeatedly time hopping to thwart him, improved the agency as a whole.

So, the implication is strong that yes, he knows.  However, it is an important part of the film's story is that the viewer has to make their own interpretation.